# Confirm invoice only by user from usergroup

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have user group(that is not working properly now)
and I want that only users in this group could confirm invoice that is in state = 'draft' and type = 'in_refund' all other users should get an error that they not in this particular group. I think that I need to create a method in `account.invoice` that will check if the user in this group but I have no clue how.

```xml
  <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_management">
      <field name="name">Asortment</field>
      <field name="description">User access level for this module</field>
      <field name="sequence">3</field>
    </record>

   <record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
     <field name="name">Manager</field>
     <field name="category_id" ref="account.group_manager"/>
    </record>



"id"    "name"  "model_id:id"   "group_id:id"   "perm_read" "perm_write"    "perm_create"   "perm_unlink"
"User"  "Asortment" "model_account_invoice" "account.group_manager" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

Comment: why you dont put the groups in button? so button will be hide if user not have access

Comment: Yej but I need UserError, unfortunately, to notify users that they need to ask an administrator to be added to the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying the `groups` in button definition.

Ex:

```xml
 <button name="function_name" type="object" string="Confirm" groups="module_name.group_manager"/>
```

The button **Confirm** is only visible to the users in the `group_manager` group.

**OR**

You can use `has_group` function to check whether the user belongs to the group `group_manager`.

```py
if self.env.user.has_group('account.group_supplier_inv_check_total'):
    // Write your statement

else:

     raise UserError(_('Your error message'))
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yej but I need UserError, unfortunately, to notify users that they need to ask an administrator to be added to the group